# Polynomial multiplication in c

Tags: c, polynomials

I am attempting to create a polynomial multiplication program in C, where I have implemented a function named `pmult` for the multiplication of two polynomials. The program works well until the point where polynomials need to be added for the same exponent values. At this stage, I encounter a segmentation fault with the error message:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
```

What should I do?

Example i used:

```
p1:
No. of elements=5
coeff expo
2     6  
5     3
3     2
2     1
3     0
p2:
No. of elements=5
coeff expo
3     7  
2     6
5     4
3     2
7     0
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct poly {
    int coeff;
    int expo;
} poly;

poly *pmult(poly *p1, poly *p2, int term1, int term2, int term, int *ptr);
poly *create(int term);
void display(poly *p, int term);

poly *create(int term)
{
    poly *p = malloc(term * sizeof(poly));
    for (int i = 0; i < term; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the coefficient and the exponent of the polynomial:");
        scanf("%d%d", &p[i].coeff, &p[i].expo);
    }
    return p;
}

poly *pmult(poly *p1, poly *p2, int term1, int term2, int term, int *ptr)
{
    poly *p3 = malloc(term * sizeof(poly));
    int k = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < term1; i++)  //Multiplies every poly1's term with every poly2's term and stores them in poly3
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < term2; j++)
        {
            p3[k].coeff = p1[i].coeff * p2[j].coeff;
            p3[k++].expo = p1[i].expo + p2[j].expo;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Displaying poly3:\n");
    display(p3, k);
    int max = p3[0].expo;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (p3[i].expo > max)
        {
            max = p3[i].expo;
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nMAXXXXX..........:%d\n", max);
    int h = 0;
    poly *p4 = malloc(k * sizeof(poly));
    
    for (int i = max; i >= 0; i--)  //if we have a polynomial result as 3X5+4X3+6X3+7X3+3X3+0X2 so we need to format it as 3X5+20X3+0X2
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (i == p3[j].expo)
            {
                sum += p3[j].coeff;
            }
        }
        if (sum > 0)
        {
            p4[h].expo = i;
            p4[h++].coeff = sum;
        }
    }
    
    free(p3);
    *ptr = h;
    return p4;
}

void display(poly *p, int term)
{
    printf("Printing a polynomial......\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < term; i++)
    {
        printf("%dX%d + ", p[i].coeff, p[i].expo);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int termp1, termp2;
    
    printf("Enter the no of terms in polynomial one:");
    scanf("%d", &termp1);
    
    poly *poly1 = create(termp1);
    display(poly1, termp1);
    
    printf("Enter the no of terms in polynomial one:");
    scanf("%d", &termp2);
    poly *poly2 = create(termp2);
    
    display(poly2, termp2);
    
    int term = termp1 + termp2;
    int ptr = 0;
    
    poly *poly3 = pmult(poly1, poly2, termp1, termp2, term, &ptr);
    
    display(poly3, ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: What's that????

Comment: A memory checking utility on Linux.

Comment: linux??Can't it be done on windows

Comment: i will  need to use Virtual Machine

Comment: You are trying to write `term1 * term2` values to poly3 but only have space for `term1 + term2`

Comment: @stark Thanks a lot the program worked perfectly after that correction actually i forgot that '

Comment: `i, j , k, h p1, p2, p3` use more meaningful variable names. Do not save keyboard

Comment: @HarshalMalani Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method to compute the polynomial product requires a temporary storage of `termp1 * termp2` terms instead of the expected maximum of `termp1 + termp2`. There is buffer overflow when storing some of the computed terms, invoking undefined behavior, corrupting the memory allocation data, as reported by the C library.

Here is a modified version for you to study:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct poly {
    int coeff;
    int expo;
} poly;

poly *poly_read(const char *name, int *pterms);
poly *poly_normalize(poly *p, int *pterms);
void poly_display(const char *name, const poly *p, int term);
poly *poly_multiply(const poly *p1, const poly *p2, int term1, int term2, int *pterms);

static int flush_input(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

poly *poly_read(const char *name, int *pterms)
{
    printf("Enter the no of terms in polynomial %s: ", name);
    if (scanf("%d", pterms) != 1 || *pterms <= 0) {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    poly *p = malloc(*pterms * sizeof(poly));
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < *pterms; i++) {
        printf("Enter the coefficient and the exponent of the term: ");
        while (scanf("%d%d", &p[i].coeff, &p[i].expo) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
            if (flush_input() == EOF) {
                free(p);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return poly_normalize(p, pterms);
}

int compare_terms(const void *aa, const void *bb)
{
    const poly *a = aa;
    const poly *b = bb;
    return (a->expo < b->expo) - (a->expo > b->expo);
}

poly *poly_normalize(poly *p, int *pterms)
{
    int terms = *pterms;
    int i, k;

    if (terms <= 0 || p == NULL) {
        // ensure at least one term
        free(p);
        p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        if (p != NULL) {
            *pterms = 1;
            p[0].coeff = 0;
            p[0].expo = 0;
        }
        return p;
    }

    // Sort the terms by decreasing powers
    qsort(p, terms, sizeof(*p), compare_terms);

    // Normalize terms
    for (k = 0, i = 1; i < terms; i++) {
        if (p[k].expo == p[i].expo) {
            p[k].coeff += p[i].coeff;
        } else {
            if (p[k].coeff)
                k++;
            p[k] = p[i];
        }
    }
    // handle the last term: ensure at least one term
    if (k == 0 || p[k].coeff) {
        k++;
    }
    *pterms = k;
    // try and reallocate the normalized polynonial
    poly *p1 = realloc(p, k * sizeof(poly));
    if (p1)
        return p1;
    else
        return p;
}

poly *poly_multiply(const poly *p1, const poly *p2, int term1, int term2, int *pterms)
{
    int term3 = term1 * term2;
    poly *p3 = malloc(term3 * sizeof(poly));
    if (p3 == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        *pterms = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    *pterms = term3;

    int i, j, k = 0;

    //Multiply every poly1's term with every poly2's term and stores them in poly3
    for (i = 0; i < term1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < term2; j++, k++) {
            p3[k].coeff = p1[i].coeff * p2[j].coeff;
            p3[k].expo = p1[i].expo + p2[j].expo;
        }
    }
    poly_display("temp", p3, term3);

    return poly_normalize(p3, pterms);
}

int poly_display_term(const poly *p, int i)
{
    int coeff = p[i].coeff;
    int expo = p[i].expo;
    int len = 0;

    if (coeff < 0) {
        len += printf("-");
        coeff = -coeff;
    } else
    if (coeff > 0) {
        if (i > 0) {
            len += printf("+");
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    if (coeff != 1 || expo == 0) {
        len += printf("%d", coeff);
    }
    if (expo > 0) {
        printf("X");
        if (expo > 1)
            printf("%d", expo);
    }
    return len;
}

void poly_display(const char *name, const poly *p, int term)
{
    int len = 0;
    if (name) {
        printf("%s: ", name);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < term; i++) {
        len += poly_display_term(p, i);
    }
    if (len == 0) {
        printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int termp1, termp2, termp3;

    poly *poly1 = poly_read("poly1", &termp1);
    if (poly1 == NULL)
        return 1;
    poly_display("poly1", poly1, termp1);

    poly *poly2 = poly_read("poly2", &termp2);
    if (poly2 == NULL)
        return 1;
    poly_display("poly2", poly2, termp2);

    poly *poly3 = poly_multiply(poly1, poly2, termp1, termp2, &termp3);
    if (poly3) {
        poly_display("poly3", poly3, termp3);
    }
    free(poly1);
    free(poly2);
    free(poly3);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more user-friendly polynomial parser:

```
/* realloc block or free and return NULL */
void *realloc_or_free(void *p, size_t size) {
    void *new_p = realloc(p, size);
    if (new_p == NULL)
        free(p);
    return new_p;
}

poly *poly_read(const char *name, int *pterms)
{
#if 0
    printf("Enter the no of terms in polynomial %s: ", name);
    if (scanf("%d", pterms) != 1 || *pterms <= 0) {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    poly *p = malloc(*pterms * sizeof(poly));
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *pterms; i++) {
        printf("Enter the coefficient and the exponent of the term: ");
        while (scanf("%d%d", &p[i].coeff, &p[i].expo) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
            if (flush_input() == EOF) {
                free(p);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return poly_normalize(p, pterms);
#else
    char line[200];

    printf("Enter polynomial %s: ", name);
    if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    poly *p1 = NULL;
    int terms = 0;
    unsigned char c;
    char *p = line;
    int sign = 1;

    while ((c = *p++) != '\0') {
        if (isspace(c))
            continue;
        if (c == '-') {
            sign = -sign;
            continue;
        }
        if (c == '+')
            continue;

        p1 = realloc_or_free(p1, (terms + 1) * sizeof(*p1));
        if (!p1) {
            printf("allocation error\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        p1[terms].coeff = 1;
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            p1[terms].coeff = strtol(p - 1, &p, 10);
            c = ' ';
            if (*p == 'X' || *p == 'x')
                c = *p++;
        }
        p1[terms].coeff *= sign;
        p1[terms].expo = 0;
        if (c == 'X' || c == 'x') {
            p1[terms].expo = 1;
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) {
                p1[terms].expo = strtol(p, &p, 10);
            }
        } else
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            printf("syntax error\n");
            printf("%s%*s\n", line, (int)(p - line - 1), "^");
            free(p1);
            return NULL;
        }
        terms++;
        sign = 1;
    }
    *pterms = terms;
    return poly_normalize(p1, pterms);
#endif
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter polynomial poly1: x3-1
poly1: X3-1
Enter polynomial poly2: x4-1
poly2: X4-1
temp: X7-X3-X4+1
poly3: X7-X4-X3+1
```